# does solr can be used with hdfs to search records based on keywords?

Tags: solr

Does **Apache Solr** can be used as a search engine to search for records on HDFS files (orc format) by giving any keyword through **solr**??

Let's say if I give a mobile number as a keyword will it be able to search relevant records having that mobile number in a hive table or a back end orc file in HDFS?

Comment: Did you try to google your question? Take a look at this github project https://github.com/lucidworks/hive-solr

Comment: Another github project that I like the most is Spark Solr. Youn can push/index your data from Hadoop to Solr. https://github.com/lucidworks/spark-solr

Comment: OK Thanks will go through